# prevent multiple instances of same php script

Tags: php, linux, bash, ubuntu-16.04

I am executing the following bash script on ubuntu 16.04 virtua machine startup with rc.local.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Loop forever (until break is issued)
(while true; do

   sudo php /var/www/has/index.php external communication

done ) &
```

As you can see, the bash executes a php script continuously. Over time, the script might take longer time to execute. Sometime scripts like the one above keep starting even though another instance of that same script is running. So, i want to know how can I prevent a new instance of the php script to execute, if there is an existing instance?

Answer (score 3):

You can use file locking to acquire an exclusive lock.  If the lock exists, you can end the script or wait until the lock is released.

I suggest you read up on http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php

```
$fp = fopen("/tmp/lock.txt", "r+");

if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {  // acquire an exclusive lock
    // Execute logic
} else {
    echo "Couldn't get the lock!";
}
```